# Add "+" character in between every character in AppleScript List

Tags: python, shell, applescript

**I'm trying to edit a list of shortcuts and separate keys with a "+" character.**

So "⌃⌥B" becomes "⌃+⌥+B" and so on

So far I've been able to extract my shortcuts into a list named "hotkeyShortcutList".

My example hotkeyShortcutList list looks like this:

```
set hotkeyShortcutList to {"$", "U", "J", "G", "R", "⇧R", "⇧Y", "⇧G", "⇧B", "⇧P", "⇧⌫", "⌃M", "⌃W", "⌃S", "⌃X", "⌃C", "⌃V", "⌃N", "⇧⌃N", "⌃U", "⌃B", "⇧⌃A", "⌃A", "⌥I", "⌥O", "⇧⌥I", "⇧⌥O", "⌥B", "⌥D", "⌥S", "⌃⌥M", "⌃⌥B", "⌃⌥X", "⇧⌃G", "⇧⌃⌥R", "⇧⌃⌥L", "⌃Å", "⌃]", "⇧⌃Å", "⇧⌃}", "⇧⌃M", "⇧⌃⌥!", "⇧⌃⌥@", "⇧⌃⌥£", "⇧⌃⌥$", "⇧⌃⌥%", "⇧⌃⌥^", "⌃1", "⌃2", "⌃3", "⌃4", "⌃5", "⌃6", "⇧⌃!", "⇧⌃\"", "⇧⌃#", "⇧⌃€", "⇧⌃%", "⇧⌃&", "K", "⌃K", "⌃V", "⇧⌃⌥K", "A", "Y", "Z", "⇧⌃*", "⇧⌃⌥*", "X", "⌃,", "⌃.", "⇧⌃;", "⇧⌃:", "⌃P", "⇧⌃)", "⇧⌃?", "⌃+", "Space", "[", "]", "V", "L", "P", "S", "N", "Q", "O", "T", "E", "D", "W", "C", "F"}
```

My script for processing so far:

```
set processedShortcutList to {}
repeat with i from 1 to length of hotkeyShortcutList
set theCurrentListItem to item i of hotkeyShortcutList
set processedListItem to (do shell script ("<<<" & theCurrentListItem & " sed -E 's/.{1}/&+/g ; s/-$//'"))
set processedListItem to characters 1 thru -2 of processedListItem as text
set end of processedShortcutList to processedListItem
end repeat
return processedShortcutList
```

However I've got 3 issues:

1. The shell script seems to work on regular characters, but bugs out when trying to handle special characters like "⇧", "⌃" and "⌥". I have very limited understanding of shell scripts, but it seemed to be the way to go with text handling from what I could Google...
2. I need to replace special characters with text after the "+"'s have been added. ⇧ replaced with "shift", ⌃ replaced with "control", ⌥ replaced with "command", ⌥ replaced with "command" etc.
3. I'd like to add some edge case protection to keys that have multiple letters like "space" for spacebar and "F1" for F-keys, so I don't end up with "s+p+a+c+e" and "F+1".

I know AppleScript might not be the easiest way to do it, but I'll be using the values inside of an AppleScript, so I feel like it would be nice to keep it all together. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just an FYI: `set processedListItem to (do shell script ("<<<" & theCurrentListItem & " sed -E 's/.{1}/&+/g ; s/-$//'"))` fails with: error "sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching '\"' sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file" number 2" -- Use the following instead:     `set processedListItem to do shell script "export LANG=en_us.UTF-8; sed -E 's/.{1}/&+/g ; s/-$//' <<< " & theCurrentListItem's quoted form`

Comment: You could also ask at https://apple.stackexchange.com/, I'd imagine some applescript experts hang out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method that is faster than the other answers as it does not need to run in a `repeat` *loop* as it coerces the *list* to *linefeed* separated *text* to process it with a single `do shell script` *command* and `sed`, then coerces the result of the `do shell script` *command* back to a list.

In testing in **Script Debugger** the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* took 0.01 second, while the code in the answer from red_menace took 0.05 seconds, and the code in the answer from Mockman took 0.93 second.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set hotkeyShortcutList to {"$", "U", "J", "G", "R", "⇧R", "⇧Y", "⇧G", "⇧B", "⇧P", "⇧⌫", "⌃M", "⌃W", "⌃S", "⌃X", "⌃C", "⌃V", "⌃N", "⇧⌃N", "⌃U", "⌃B", "⇧⌃A", "⌃A", "⌥I", "⌥O", "⇧⌥I", "⇧⌥O", "⌥B", "⌥D", "⌥S", "⌃⌥M", "⌃⌥B", "⌃⌥X", "⇧⌃G", "⇧⌃⌥R", "⇧⌃⌥L", "⌃Å", "⌃]", "⇧⌃Å", "⇧⌃}", "⇧⌃M", "⇧⌃⌥!", "⇧⌃⌥@", "⇧⌃⌥£", "⇧⌃⌥$", "⇧⌃⌥%", "⇧⌃⌥^", "⌃1", "⌃2", "⌃3", "⌃4", "⌃5", "⌃6", "⇧⌃!", "⇧⌃\"", "⇧⌃#", "⇧⌃€", "⇧⌃%", "⇧⌃&", "K", "⌃K", "⌃V", "⇧⌃⌥K", "A", "Y", "Z", "⇧⌃*", "⇧⌃⌥*", "X", "⌃,", "⌃.", "⇧⌃;", "⇧⌃:", "⌃P", "⇧⌃)", "⇧⌃?", "⌃+", "Space", "[", "]", "V", "L", "P", "S", "N", "Q", "O", "T", "E", "D", "W", "C", "F"}

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed
set foo to hotkeyShortcutList as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {}

set processedShortcutList to paragraphs of (do shell script "sed -e 's/⌃/control+/g' -e 's/⌥/option+/g' -e 's/⇧/shift+/g' -e 's/⌫/backspace+/g' <<< " & foo's quoted form)
```

**Result:**

```
{"$", "U", "J", "G", "R", "shift+R", "shift+Y", "shift+G", "shift+B", "shift+P", "shift+backspace+", "control+M", "control+W", "control+S", "control+X", "control+C", "control+V", "control+N", "shift+control+N", "control+U", "control+B", "shift+control+A", "control+A", "option+I", "option+O", "shift+option+I", "shift+option+O", "option+B", "option+D", "option+S", "control+option+M", "control+option+B", "control+option+X", "shift+control+G", "shift+control+option+R", "shift+control+option+L", "control+Å", "control+]", "shift+control+Å", "shift+control+}", "shift+control+M", "shift+control+option+!", "shift+control+option+@", "shift+control+option+£", "shift+control+option+$", "shift+control+option+%", "shift+control+option+^", "control+1", "control+2", "control+3", "control+4", "control+5", "control+6", "shift+control+!", "shift+control+\"", "shift+control+#", "shift+control+€", "shift+control+%", "shift+control+&", "K", "control+K", "control+V", "shift+control+option+K", "A", "Y", "Z", "shift+control+*", "shift+control+option+*", "X", "control+,", "control+.", "shift+control+;", "shift+control+:", "control+P", "shift+control+)", "shift+control+?", "control++", "Space", "[", "]", "V", "L", "P", "S", "N", "Q", "O", "T", "E", "D", "W", "C", "F"}
```

Comment: This solution seems quite nice, and also builds on the "appending a plus sign — all in one" idea. It means that I would have to make sure that the shortcuts always start with modifier keys and then follows with the key pressed (Shortcut can not be = "O⇧⌥") since it adds it after. However the way I'm extracting shortcuts seems to always do it in this way. If this works this would also be protection for the edge cases of "Space", "Page Up", "F-Keys" etc. - I'm going to be doing some testing to see if I can implement this into my code today

Comment: @BaldrianSector If your source of shortcuts does have the modifers after the key, then you could probably run a second sed (or maybe an awk) to re-order the result. Out of curiosity, what is the use case here? I considered the slowness of my solution but assumed that the usage was likely a one-off, so optimizing time would greatly exceed time savings.

Comment: @Mockman a bit of elaboration: I'm running a software called QLab (industry standard for running theatre plays) that has its own little programming built in. (it runs AppleScript directly from the software)

Everything in the software can be triggered by hotkeys. It has a button to copy all triggers set and I'm trying to get those triggers visualized with an open source project called Shortcut Mapper by Waldo Bronchart. I need the shortcuts to be in a specific format. So I'm making a script to extract, format and update project files every time something in the QLab file has been changed.

Comment: @Mockman, RE: "so optimizing would take longer than time savings." -- Not if it was written in an optimized manner to begin with, as in the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ in my answer.

Comment: @Mockman I wasn’t considering speed of the script at all, but it sure seems like a nice benefit. Idea is to run the script every time I change the hotkeys in QLab or load up somebody else’s file. (Which will happen quite often) It's not going to be running all the time, but it's more than a one-off thing.

The appending a plus sign — all in one is for sure a brilliant idea, and fortunately enough it looks like the "Copy Trigger Text" in QLab (my way of extracting shortcuts) always places the modifiers at the start of the shortcuts.

Comment: @user3439894 another great benefit of your solution is that since I'm digging my way down the AppleScript hole (that its the primary way to interact with my software) I'd love to see different ways of doing things. So learning optimized ways of programming are highly appreciated!

Comment: @user3439894 You're very awesome.

Comment: @BaldrianSector Sounds like an interesting project. I just took a quick perusal of the two apps you mention and it makes sense now. Used to be that you would buy special keyboards that were app-specific for several of the big graphic/video apps.

Comment: Yep. I remember the physical overlay skins you could (and probably still can) get as an overview of shortcuts. Shortcut Mapper tries to do that in a digital format and makes it easy to update when stuff changes. It's not been updated too much, but seems like a good foundation to build on, so I don't have to start from scratch. I really wanted something like this for a while since I program custom functions into my QLab files and trigger them with shortcuts. Shortcut Mapper seems like the closest thing I could find, to what I've been wanting.

Answer (score 1):

How about just replacing the special characters with their descriptive word and appending a plus sign — all in one go? As you have a modest number of odd characters, this has the benefit of obviousness as well as making it easy to add or edit substitutions.

```
set hotkeyShortcutList to {"$", "U", "J", "G", "R", "⇧R", "⇧Y", "⇧G", "⇧B", "⇧P", "⇧⌫", "⌃M", "⌃W", "⌃S", "⌃X", "⌃C", "⌃V", "⌃N", "⇧⌃N", "⌃U", "⌃B", "⇧⌃A", "⌃A", "⌥I", "⌥O", "⇧⌥I", "⇧⌥O", "⌥B", "⌥D", "⌥S", "⌃⌥M", "⌃⌥B", "⌃⌥X", "⇧⌃G", "⇧⌃⌥R", "⇧⌃⌥L", "⌃Å", "⌃]", "⇧⌃Å", "⇧⌃}", "⇧⌃M", "⇧⌃⌥!", "⇧⌃⌥@", "⇧⌃⌥£", "⇧⌃⌥$", "⇧⌃⌥%", "⇧⌃⌥^", "⌃1", "⌃2", "⌃3", "⌃4", "⌃5", "⌃6", "⇧⌃!", "⇧⌃\"", "⇧⌃#", "⇧⌃€", "⇧⌃%", "⇧⌃&", "K", "⌃K", "⌃V", "⇧⌃⌥K", "A", "Y", "Z", "⇧⌃*", "⇧⌃⌥*", "X", "⌃,", "⌃.", "⇧⌃;", "⇧⌃:", "⌃P", "⇧⌃)", "⇧⌃?", "⌃+", "Space", "[", "]", "V", "L", "P", "S", "N", "Q", "O", "T", "E", "D", "W", "C", "F"}

set newList to {}
repeat with hotkey in hotkeyShortcutList
    do shell script "echo '" & hotkey & "' | sed -e 's/⌃/control+/g' -e 's/⌥/option+/g' -e 's/⇧/shift+/g' -e 's/⌫/backspace+/g'"
    set end of newList to result
end repeat
newList
```

NB You have some odd characters in your source text. For example, your 'control' character is actually an 'up arrowhead' (U+2303). If your text ever has the more conventional 'circumflex accent' (U+005E) then you will need to edit the sed parameter.

The above generates the following result for me with your source list. Let me know if this is the desired output.

```
{"$", "U", "J", "G", "R", "shift+R", "shift+Y", "shift+G", "shift+B", "shift+P", "shift+backspace+", "control+M", "control+W", "control+S", "control+X", "control+C", "control+V", "control+N", "shift+control+N", "control+U", "control+B", "shift+control+A", "control+A", "option+I", "option+O", "shift+option+I", "shift+option+O", "option+B", "option+D", "option+S", "control+option+M", "control+option+B", "control+option+X", "shift+control+G", "shift+control+option+R", "shift+control+option+L", "control+Å", "control+]", "shift+control+Å", "shift+control+}", "shift+control+M", "shift+control+option+!", "shift+control+option+@", "shift+control+option+£", "shift+control+option+$", "shift+control+option+%", "shift+control+option+^", "control+1", "control+2", "control+3", "control+4", "control+5", "control+6", "shift+control+!", "shift+control+\"", "shift+control+#", "shift+control+€", "shift+control+%", "shift+control+&", "K", "control+K", "control+V", "shift+control+option+K", "A", "Y", "Z", "shift+control+*", "shift+control+option+*", "X", "control+,", "control+.", "shift+control+;", "shift+control+:", "control+P", "shift+control+)", "shift+control+?", "control++", "Space", "[", "]", "V", "L", "P", "S", "N", "Q", "O", "T", "E", "D", "W", "C", "F"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some AppleScriptObjC (OK, just about everything) might be faster, but even doing it the long way with regular AppleScript winds up being way faster without using the shell script, since the overhead of calling the shell script multiple times is expensive.  On my machine the shell script events take up 94% of the time, and your script still has more to do.

The long way involves stepping through the characters of each hotkey item, replacing special characters with their description as it goes, and adding the `+` separators.  The edge cases are taken care of while going through the characters by using a regular `space` in the hotkey item and replacing it the same as the other modifier characters, and by just appending the rest of the hotkey string once it finds an `F` (modifier keys typically come first).

Note that the symbol for control `⌃` is different than the caret `^` (shift+6):

```
set hotkeyShortcutList to {"$", "U", "J", "G", "R", "⇧R", "⇧Y", "⇧G", "⇧B", "⇧P", "⇧⌫", "⌃M", "⌃W", "⌃^", "⌃X", "⌃C", "⌃V", "⌃N", "⇧⌃N", "⌃U", "⌃B", "⇧⌃A", "⌃A", "⌥I", "⌥O", "⇧⌥I", "⇧⌥O", "⌥B", "⌥D", "⌥S", "⌃⌥M", "⌃⌥B", "⌃⌥X", "⇧⌃G", "⇧⌃⌥R", "⇧⌃⌥L", "⌃Å", "⌃]", "⇧⌃Å", "⇧⌃}", "⇧⌃M", "⇧⌃⌥!", "⇧⌃⌥@", "⇧⌃⌥£", "⇧⌃⌥$", "⇧⌃⌥%", "⇧⌃⌥^", "⌃1", "⌃2", "⌃3", "⌃4", "⌃5", "⌃6", "⇧⌃!", "⇧⌃\"", "⇧⌃#", "⇧⌃€", "⇧⌃%", "⇧⌃&", "K", "⌃K", "⌃V", "⇧⌃⌥K", "A", "Y", "Z", "⇧⌃*", "⇧⌃⌥*", "X", "⌃,", "⌃.", "⇧⌃;", "⇧⌃:", "⌃P", "⇧⌃)", "⇧⌃?", "⌃+", "⌘ ", "[", "]", "V", "L", "P", "S", "N", "Q", "O", "T", "E", "D", "W", "C", "⌘F1", "⌃F12"}
set replacements to {{" ", "space"}, {"⇧", "shift"}, {"⌃", "control"}, {"⌥", "option"}, {"⌘", "command"}, {"↵", "enter"}, {"↩", "return"}, {"⌫", "backspace"}} -- key symbols to replace

set processedShortcutList to {}

repeat with anItem in hotkeyShortcutList
    set processedItem to ""
    set anItem to contents of anItem
    repeat with here from 1 to (count anItem)
        set char to item here of anItem
        repeat with replacement in replacements -- replace key symbol with its description
            if first item of replacement is char then
                set char to second item of replacement
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
        considering case and diacriticals -- tighten the comparison a little
            if char is "F" then -- can be function key, so just append the rest
                set processedItem to processedItem & text here thru -1 of anItem & "+"
                exit repeat
            end if
        end considering
        set processedItem to processedItem & char & "+"
    end repeat
    set end of processedShortcutList to text 1 thru -2 of processedItem -- strip last
end repeat

return processedShortcutList
```